# Windows Phone Binding Image Location

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, binding, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to place a collection of images at certain places on a canvas through Binding.

For some reason, the images are displaying but are NOT at the locations which I have specified.

**C#**

```
_roomView.Room = new Room
{
   Items = new List<Item> {
   new Item {ImageUri = "/Escape;component/Images/Items/a.jpg", XPosition = 190, YPosition = 50},
   new Item {ImageUri = "/Escape;component/Images/Items/b.png", XPosition = 390, YPosition = 100},
   new Item {ImageUri = "/Escape;component/Images/Items/b.png", XPosition = 490, YPosition = 600}}
};

listBoxItems.ItemsSource = _roomView.Room.Items;
```

**XML**

```
<Canvas>
     <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}" Stretch="None" Canvas.Left="{Binding Room.Items.XPosition}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Room.Items.YPosition}"/>
</Canvas>
```

`XPosition` and `YPosition` are of type int. I have tried changing them to double but the images still aren't being displayed where I want them to be. They only get displayed at the top left of the screen - on top of each other.

Can anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the pack `URI` format which is only valid if your images have a `Build Action` of "`Embedded Resource`". Even then, I'm not sure this `URI` format is actually supported for `Image.Source` and if the `URI` has to be `Relative` or `Absolute`. Check the images `Build Action` (`Right click --> Properties` on those files) and try changing the `UriKind`.

Either way, unless you have a very good reason it's best to keep media assets as:
`Build Action = Content` and use the normal path `URIs`. Adding images to `DLLs` as Embedded Resources is bad for startup performance since it takes longer to load your bigger `DLLs` into the `AppDomain`.
It's also bad from a memory usage perspective since the `DLLs` loaded into memory are now bigger.

Bottom line:

`<Image Source="myPicture.png" />` format is much better for performance than

`<Image Source="myAssemblyName;component/myPicture.png" />` syntax.

Comment: The URI isn't the problem. It's the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties which aren't working. The URI's are binding perfectly fine. It's the XPosition and YPosition which aren't going across - i.e. the images aren't where they're suppose to be.

Comment: Is Items a Collection? Does "Room.Items" actually how those properties? Or does an item in the "Room.Items" collection have that property?

Comment: Items is a collection, yes. And yes, an Item has properties of XPosition and YPosition.

Comment: OK, but the Items Collection itself doesn't have "XPosition" and "YPosition". You see why your binding expression isn't working? A better binding expression here might be *Canvas.Top="{Binding Room.Items[0].YPosition}"*.

Comment: but if I do [0] then they'll ALL be at the same place.

Answer (score 1):

Your C# code has collection of images.

Your XAML only shows a single image. If the XAML is in the listbox data template, you'll get several canvases, with 1 image each.

To display a collection of images on the single Canvas, you could use e.g. `<ItemsControl>`, set ItemsPanel to a Canvas, and in the data template you specify a single image with source, canvas.left and canvas.top.

If you're trying to do what I've described with a ListBox instead of ItemsControl, it wont work because it has one more layer of UI elements between ItemsPanel and item, namely the item container.

P.S. Fastest way to troubleshoot such GUI problems - [XAML Spy](http://xamlspy.com/download), I've bought myself a personal license. Evaluation is 21 days long, fully functional.

Comment: Thank you Soonts. Could you kindly make the XAML so I can see exactly what you mean? Please?